# Sort range based on a column using google sheets api java

Tags: java, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to sort all rows in a given range based on a column. 
I have tried this:

```
BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest busReq = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
SortSpec ss = new SortSpec();
// ordering ASCENDING or DESCENDING
ss.setSortOrder("DESCENDING");
// the column number starting from 0
ss.setDimensionIndex(1);
SortRangeRequest srr = new SortRangeRequest();
srr.setSortSpecs(Arrays.asList(ss));
Request req = new Request();
req.setSortRange(srr);
busReq.setRequests(Arrays.asList(req));
// mService is a instance of com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets
this.mService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, busReq).execute();
```

But the problem is it's sorting a specific column where I want to sort all the rows based on that column. Any suggestion?

Basically I want to achieve this, with sheets API java: [image]

Answer (score 0):

### Approach

You will have to define the range for your `SortRangeRequest` Object. To do so you can use the `setRange(GridRange range)` method.

Like this:

```
        SortRangeRequest srr = new SortRangeRequest();
        GridRange gr = new GridRange();
        Integer sheetId = 0;
        Integer startRowIndex = 0;
        Integer endRowIndex = 1004;
        Integer startColumnIndex = 0;
        Integer endColumnIndex = 25;
        /**
         * From the docs:
         * "range": {
         *    "sheetId": sheetId,
         *    "startRowIndex": 0,
         *    "endRowIndex": 10,
         *    "startColumnIndex": 0,
         *    "endColumnIndex": 6
         * }
         */
        gr.setSheetId(sheetId);
        gr.setStartRowIndex(startRowIndex);
        gr.setEndRowIndex(endRowIndex);
        gr.setStartColumnIndex(startColumnIndex);
        gr.setEndColumnIndex(endColumnIndex);
        srr.setRange(gr);
```

### Reference

[Sort Range Reqest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/data#sort_a_range_with_multiple_sorting_specifications)